# How to display a value from one column to the other column row in MYSql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to display values present in the 2nd column of table to the 1st column of the table. I'll be joining two table and I'll be getting the parent id of the 1st column in the second column. I want to display parent id along with the child id in the first column? Is there any way to achieve this?

```
Child table   
 child_id      
   1
   3
   5
   7
   9




Parent table 
parent_id
    2       
    4       
    6      
    8       
    10  




child_id| parent_id
1       | 2
3       | 2
5       | 2
*2      | 2*
7       | 5
9       | 5
*5      | 5*
```

As mentioned above, I want to display parent id '2' just after 3 rows displaying the child ids,similarly I want to display parent id '5' just after 5 rows displaying the child ids.

Rows indicated in starts should be displayed from parent_id column

Query will be something like 
`select ci.child_id,pi.parent_id from child_table JOIN parent_table on ci.child_id=pi.parent_id. group by child_id`.

The corresponding parent_id for child_id should be displayed at the end of all the child_id in child_id column.

Comment: Can u give the the expected output

Comment: You are using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @Code-Monk,Using MySQL

Comment: @RajaYuvi,Can you please look at the edited question. What I have shown in two columns in the expected result.